# How to use stringstreams to find the sum of integers inside a string?

Tags: c++, addition, stringstream

I have a string with 6 Integer numbers inside of it '''string myStr = "1 2 3 4 5 6"'''

I want to use a stringstream to read all of those numbers individually and add them all up to find the sum.

This is part of a homework problem, just to clarify, and I need to use stringstreams as a way to read the string and add up all the numbers inside.

Here is the prompt:

"Create a string with a series of six numbers. With the help of a stringstream, add all numbers in the string"

Note: 
Sorry if this is a badly structured question. any criticism of how I could make this more clear is appreciated.

I have searched for a way to do this but I am having trouble understanding just exactly how this works.

I know you need to use '''ostringstream''' or '''istringstream''' to do whatever it is I am trying to do. But I do not know HOW to use them.

I do have a coursebook "Murach's C++ Programming" which is the book we have for reference in class. But it does not go over anything about stringstreams in any other context besides reading from text files.

```
void stringstreams(string myStr = "1 2 3 4 5 6"){

    stringstream strStream;
    strStream << myStr;

    myStr = strStream.str();
    cout << myStr << endl;

}
```

Describe results:

I think all this does is send the string into a stringstream, and then send it right back the other way (I may be completely wrong about that). I am not exactly sure what to do because I don't have ANY experience whatsoever working with stringstream.

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use the formatted extraction operator, `>>`, and everything will be crystal clear to you.

Comment: **Let me Google that for you**: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/  There's code at the bottom of the page on how to read a sequence of numbers from a stringstream that was constructed from a string made up of a list of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to use the `std::stringstream`, without having to manually convert the string to an integer:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::string myStr = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
    std::stringstream strm(myStr);
    int value;
    int sum = 0;
    while (strm >> value)
        sum += value;
    std::cout << sum << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this simple commented code helps:

```
int main() {
    std::string myStr = "1 2 3 4 5 6";
    std::stringstream ss{ myStr}; // Initialize the stringstream; use stringstream instead if you are confused with ostringstream vs istringstream
    string str;
    int sum = 0;
    while (getline(ss, str, ' ')) {  // split stringstream into tokens separated by a whitespace
        sum += std::atoi(str.c_str()); // convert each string to c- equivalent before converting to integer using atoi
    }
    std::cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to convert a string to an integer or use `getline`.  The extraction operator `>>` is all that's required, and making sure that the type being extracted to is an `int`.

Comment: I would never do it like that. Please use the answer from PaulMcKenzie